# replacing columns values only on specific columns using regex in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I want to replace the values of specific columns. I can change the values one by one but, I have hundreds of columns and I need to change the columns starting with a specific string. Here is an example, I want to replace the string when the column name starts with `"Q14"`

```
df.filter(regex = 'Q14').replace(1, 'Selected').replace(0, 'Not selected')
```

The above code is working. But, how I can implement it in my `dataframe`? As this is the function so I can't use inplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below `df`:

```
In [439]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Q14_A':[ 1,0,0,2], 'Q14_B':[0,1,1,2], 'Q12_A':[1,0,0,0]})

In [440]: df
Out[440]: 
   Q14_A  Q14_B  Q12_A
0      1      0      1
1      0      1      0
2      0      1      0
3      2      2      0
```

Filter columns that start with `Q14`, save it in a variable:

```
In [443]: cols = df.filter(regex='^Q14').columns
```

Now, change the above selected columns with your `replace` commands:

```
In [446]: df[cols] = df[cols].replace(1, 'Selected').replace(0, 'Not selected')
```

**Output:**

```
In [447]: df
Out[447]: 
          Q14_A         Q14_B  Q12_A
0      Selected  Not selected      1
1  Not selected      Selected      0
2  Not selected      Selected      0
3             2             2      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all columns and based on matched condition apply column transformation using `apply` command:

```
for column in df.columns:
    if column.startswith("Q"):
        df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: "Selected" if x == 1 else "Not selected")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas.Series.replace dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q14_A':[ 1,0,0,2], 'Q14_B':[0,1,1,2], 'Q12_A':[1,0,0,0]})
cols = df.filter(regex='^Q14').columns

replace_map = {
    1: "Selected",
    0 : "Not Selected"

}

df[cols] = df[cols].replace(replace_map)
```